# if not using padding, is there a way to get it?

Tags: css

[image]

if foucus the input text box. the cursor is on the top, i want to locate the cursor at the center part, if not using padding-top. how should i do?

Comment: What have you done to the `input` element to make the cursor appear that way (and an icon to appear inside it)? Please share the code that creates the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
#input-field {
   height: 20px;
   line-height: 20px;
}
```

This will center the text vertically on your input field, which should center the cursor as well.

Answer (score 1):

use this -

```
img{ vertical-align: middle; }
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/KzySu/)

OR

Push the the input text element down by using -

```
input[type="text"]{
  margin: 4px 0 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
 input{
    height:      YOURIMAGE HEIGHT;
    line-height: YOURIMAGE HEIGHT; 
    display:block
 }
```